# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), foreach from Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am a bit confusing why I can not foreach child data `documentation_groups` of `products` table with Eager Loading? It respond me "Invalid argument Supplied for foreach(). Please help me check Thanks

```
// Product Model

public function documentationGroups()
{
   return $this->hasMany(DocumentationGroup::class);
}


//This is Data from Controller with Eager Loading

$productDocumentations = Product::has('documentationGroups')              
                        ->with('documentationGroups')
                        ->get();
    
 [
   {
     "id" : 1,
     "name": "ProductName" ,
     "documentation_groups": [
       {
          "id": 1,
          "product_id": 1,
          "name": "Introduction",
          "slug": "introduction",
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "product_id": 1,
          "name": "Customization",
          "slug": "customization",
         }
      ]
   }
]

// In Blade
@foreach ($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->documentation_groups as $documentationGroup)
        {{ $documentationGroup->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$product->documentation_groups` to  `$product->documentationGroups`